# Get String Before Particular Symbol PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string

Lets suppose I have String as

```
$b = 'grapes, pineapple & fruit seller offered by flipkart from usa';
```

From this string I want 3 words as follow

1. grapes
2. pineapple
3. fruit seller

The first word I get by explode()

Third word I get as follow Code

```
$bb = explode(",",$b);
$demo1 = substr($bb[1], strpos($bb[1], "&") + 1)."<br>";
$demo2 = str_replace($demo1, "", $bb[1])."<br>";
$result = substr($demo2, strpos($demo2, "&") + 1);
$newres = explode(" ",$result);
foreach($newres as $value){
    if($value == "offered"){
        break;
    }
    $myarr[] = $value;
}
$thirdkeyword = implode(" ",$myarr);
echo "Third Keyword :".$thirdkeyword."<br>";
```

Which returns me `fruit seller`.

But now I want second word **pineapple**. So how can I get the word before &(AND).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$b = 'grapes, pineapple & fruit seller offered by flipkart from usa';

$str = explode(' offered', $b)[0];
$result = preg_split('/\s*[,&]\s*/', $str);

print_r($result);
```

result

```
Array
(
    [0] => grapes
    [1] => pineapple
    [2] => fruit seller
)
```

Comment: spectacular Answer.

Comment: one request Please @splash58

Comment: `$a = 'companyname - grapes, pineapple & apple For  Sleepers Manufacturer from Delhi, India';`
From this i need grapes,pineapple and apple so is it possible using preg_filter as per your knowledge .

Comment: answer would be really helpful . Thank you Very Much.

Comment: `preg_split(): Compilation failed: lookbehind assertion is not fixed length`

Comment: it outputs me 1

Comment: Thnk youhhh So much